# Validating an HTML form on Submit with JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've been reading about how to do this, and I have the validation mostly working. It's just the actual submission I am having issues with.

Currently, the text fields are checked correctly and messages appear as they should. However, when I click submit, the form still submits, and I can't get any of the test alert messages to show after the first one.

I have tried calling validation() from onsubmit in the form tag, as well as onclick on the submit button. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.

You can ignore the php variables in the form. Those are from the old php validation we are removing.

Here's the form:

```
<form id="registrationForm" action="upload_file.php?upload='docu'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td>Email: </td>
                <td><input type="text" id="email" name="userInput" value="<?php echo  $email; ?>" onBlur="validateEmail(this.value)" onKeyUp="validateEmail(this.value)" maxlength="80" size="25"><span id="emailError" class="error">  <?php echo  $emailErr;?></span></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="userInput" id="fname" value="<?php echo  $firstName; ?>" onKeyUp="validateName(this.value,1)"  onBlur="validateName(this.value,1)"><span id="fnameError" class="error">  <?php echo  $firstNameErr;?></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="userInput" id="lname" value="<?php echo  $lastName; ?>" onKeyUp="validateName(this.value,2)"  onBlur="validateName(this.value,2)"><span id="lnameError"  class="error">  <?php echo  $lastNameErr;?></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="userInput" id="phone" value="<?php echo  $phone; ?>" maxlength="15" size="10" onBlur="validatePhone(this.value)" onKeyUp="validatePhone(this.value)"><span id="phoneError" class="error">  <?php echo  $phoneErr;?></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password: </td>
                <td><input id="password" type="password" id="password" name="userInput" maxlength="20" onBlur="validatePassword(this.value)" onKeyUp="validatePassword(this.value)"><span id="passwordError" class="error">  <?php echo  $passwordErr;?></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Confirm Password: </td>
                <td><input id="confirm" type="password" id="confirm" name="userInput" maxlength="20" onBlur="validateConfirm(this.value)" onKeyUp="validateConfirm(this.value)"> <span id="confirmError" class="error">  <?php echo  $passwordErr;?></span></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <br/>
        <hr/>
        <h2>Manuscript's Information</h2>

        <label for="synopsisFile">Synopsis:</label>
            <input type="file" name="synopsisFile" id="synopsisFile"><span class="error"><?php echo  $synopsisErr;?></span><br><br/>

        <label for="synopsisFile">Chapters:</label>
            <input type="file" name="chaptersFile" id="synopsisFile"><span class="error"><?php echo  $chaptersErr;?></span><br>

        <br/> <br/>

        <input id = "submit" type="submit" name="register_submit" value="Submit" onclick ="return validation();">  
    </form>
```

and here is the validation I'm using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateEmail(email)
{
var valid = false;
var testEmail=email;
var atpos=testEmail.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=testEmail.lastIndexOf(".");

if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=testEmail.length)
{
    document.getElementById('emailError').innerHTML = "Invalid Email";
    document.getElementById('emailError').style.color = 'red';
    valid = false;
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('emailError').innerHTML = "Valid Email";
    document.getElementById('emailError').style.color = 'green';
    valid = true;
}
return valid;
}

function validateName(name, nameType)
{
var valid = false;
var testName = name;
var testNameType = nameType;

if (testNameType == 1)
{
    if (testName == null || testName.length<=0)
    {
        document.getElementById('fnameError').innerHTML = "Invalid Name. Name must not be blank.";
        document.getElementById('fnameError').style.color = 'red';
        valid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('fnameError').innerHTML = "Valid Name";
        document.getElementById('fnameError').style.color = 'green';
        valid = true;
    }

}
else if(testNameType == 2)
{
    if (testName == null || testName.length<=0)
    {
        document.getElementById('lnameError').innerHTML = "Invalid Name. Name must not be blank.";
        document.getElementById('lnameError').style.color = 'red';
        valid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('lnameError').innerHTML = "Valid Name";
        document.getElementById('lnameError').style.color = 'green';
        valid = true;
    }
}

return valid;
}

function validatePhone(phone)
{
var valid = false;
var testPhone = phone;
var phoneFormat = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[- ]?([0-9]{3})[- ]?([0-9]{4})$/;  

if (testPhone == null || testPhone.length<=0)
{
        document.getElementById('phoneError').innerHTML = "Invalid Phone Number. Must not be blank.";
        document.getElementById('phoneError').style.color = 'red';
        valid = false;      
}
else
{
    if (!(testPhone.match(phoneFormat)))
    {
        document.getElementById('phoneError').innerHTML = "Invalid Phone Number.";
        document.getElementById('phoneError').style.color = 'red';
        valid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('phoneError').innerHTML = "Valid Phone Number";
        document.getElementById('phoneError').style.color = 'green';
        valid = true;
    }
}
return valid;
}
function validatePassword(password)
{
var valid = false;
var testPassword = password;
var MIN_CHARS = 5;

if (testPassword == null || testPassword.length<MIN_CHARS)
{
    document.getElementById('passwordError').innerHTML = "Invalid Password. Password must be at least 5 characters.";
    document.getElementById('passwordError').style.color = 'red';
    valid = false;
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('passwordError').innerHTML = "Valid Password";
    document.getElementById('passwordError').style.color = 'green';
    valid = true;
}

if (testpassword !== document.getElementById('confirm').value)    //when the password is changed, recheck the confirm password.
{
    alert(document.getElementById('confirm').value);
    document.getElementById('confirmError').innerHTML = "Passwords do not match";
    document.getElementById('confirmError').style.color = 'red';
    valid = false;

}
else
{
    alert(document.getElementById('confirm').value);
    document.getElementById('confirmError').innerHTML = "Passwords match";
    document.getElementById('confirmError').style.color = 'green';
    valid = true;
}
return valid;
}

function validateConfirm(confirmPassword)
{
var valid = false;
var testConfirm = confirmPassword;

if (testConfirm !== document.getElementById('password').value)    
{
    document.getElementById('confirmError').innerHTML = "Passwords do not Match";
    document.getElementById('confirmError').style.color = 'red';
    valid = false;

}  
else
{
    document.getElementById('confirmError').innerHTML = "Passwords match";
    document.getElementById('confirmError').style.color = 'green';
    valid = true;
}    
return valid;
}

function validation()
{    
var validData = false;

alert(validData);
alert(validateEmail(getElementById('email').value));

if (validateEmail(getElementById('email').value) == false)
{
    validData = false;
    alert("email " + validData);
}
else if(validateName(getElementById('fname',1).value) == false)
{
    validData = false;
    alert("fname " + validData);
}
else if(validatename(getElementById('lname',2).value) == false)
{
    validData = false;
    alert("lname " + validData);
}
else if(validatePhone(getElementById('phone').value) == false)
{    
    validData = false;
    alert("phone " + validData);
}
else if(validatePassword(getElementById('password').value) == false)
{
    validData = false;
    alert("password " + validData);
}
else if(validateConfirm(getElementById('confirm').value) ==false)
{
    validData = false;
    alert("confirm pass " + validData);
}
else
{
    validData = true;
}

alert(validData);
//alert(document.getElementById("validData").value);
return false;
//return validData;


}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's

```
document.getElementById('email')
```

instead of

```
getElementById('email')
```

You're doing it correct in all your functions, except for the validation function.

Comment: Oh man, I've been at this too long today. Some times all it takes is another (less tired) pair of eyes. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem. Accept the answer of scunliffe or my own, so that people know this issue is closed. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript validation function contains errors:

```
getElementById('fname',1)
```

The `getElementById(id)` method only takes 1 parameter.

However as @yvanavermaet notes you should also have "document" before the call:

```
document.getElementById(id);
```

Comment: Thanks. That (,1) is for the name validation, I had it in the wrong place. Too tired for this haha.

Answer (score 0):

Your form has other issues. Naming any form control "submit" masks the form's submit method so you can't call it, so don't use it as a name or ID. There's usually no need to give a sumbit button a name or id anyway, so just remvoe it.

Also, the form validation should be on the form's submit handler, not the submit button as forms can be submitted without pressing the submit button. Move the listener and pass a reference to the form using *this*:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return validation(this)" ...>
```

Then in the function you can access form controls by name and dispense with *getElementById* (and ID attributes). Also, if the individual validation routines return true or false, you can simplify the tests to:

```
function validate(form) {

  if (!validateEmail(form.email.value)) {
    // failed
```

Lastly, you have:

```
testPassword == null
```

*testPassword* is given the value of a form control, and form control values are always strings. A string can never equal null (even an empty string), so the above test always returns false.

Comment: That didn't work. Now none of my Javascript works, and firebug reports there is no javascript on the page at all.

Comment: Then you created a script error when you modified the code. The submit event is used by every form validation script out there for the reason I stated, as is referencing form controls as named properties the form, it's much more efficient than using *getElementById*.